# How to fix inconsistent datatypes:expected NUMBER got DATE in Oracle

Tags: date, date-arithmetic, calculation

I am receiving an error on a query that I am running. My error is 'inconsistent datatypes:expected NUMBER got DATE'
I am able to successfully do it in SQL Server so I looked up how to update the query for Oracle syntax and I am running into issues.

I have tried TO_DATE of a date field minus TO_DATE of the SYSDATE and then tried to divide that by 365 for the number of days in a year.

```
SELECT min.Contact,
                min.MIN_DATE,
                COUNT(giv.ID) AS COUNT,
                SYSDATE,
                TO_DATE(min.MIN_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')-TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATEDIFF,
                COUNT(giv.ID)/(TO_DATE(min.MIN_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')-TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')/365)
                FROM giv JOIN min
                ON giv.Contact=min.Contact
                GROUP BY min.Contact,min.MIN_DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the parenthesis. Division takes precedence over subtraction. Try this:

```
COUNT(giv.ID)/((TO_DATE(min.MIN_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')-TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'))/365)
```

Comment: Hi Francisco, thanks for your assistance. I updated that part of the query and now I am getting this error that highlights the min.MIN_DATE and says this 'ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected'

Comment: It looks like column MIN_DATE contains varchar2 values that do not correspond to the mask 'YYYY-MM-DD'. Are you able to take samples of the column and perhaps locate what those values are?